# Upperbound of Kullback-Leibler between marginals

Tags: entropy, jensen-inequality

I want to know if for every pair of $p(x, y)$ and $q(x, y)$ the following inequality
$$
\int_X p(x) \log \frac{p(x)}{q(x)} dx \leq \int_X\int_Y p(x, y) \log \frac{p(x, y)}{q(x, y)}dxdy
$$
is valid.
I tried unsuccessfully to use Jensen's and Gibbs' inequalities.

Comment: Is $p(x)$ defined as $\int_Y p(x,y) \,dy$?

Comment: Yes, it is. I think I found the solution. I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution.

$$
p(x)\log\frac{p(x)}{q(x)} \leq \int_Yp(x,y)\log\frac{p(x,y)}{q(x,y)}dy
$$

implies

$$
\int_X p(x)\log\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}dx \leq \int_X \int_Yp(x,y)\log\frac{p(x,y)}{q(x,y)}dydx
$$.

Therefore,
$$
\int_Y p(x, y) \log \frac{p(x,y)}{q(x,y)}dy \\
= p(x) \int_Y p(y | x) \log \frac{p(x,y)}{q(x,y)}dy \\
= p(x) \int_Y p(y | x) \log \frac{p(y|x)p(x)}{q(y|x)q(x)}dy \\
= p(x) \int_Y p(y | x) \bigg(\log \frac{p(y|x)}{q(y|x)} + \log \frac{p(x)}{q(x)}\bigg)dy \\
= p(x) \int_Y p(y | x)\log \frac{p(y|x)}{q(y|x)}dy  + p(x) \int_Y p(y | x) dy \log \frac{p(x)}{q(x)} \\
= p(x) \int_Y p(y | x)\log \frac{p(y|x)}{q(y|x)}dy  + p(x) \log \frac{p(x)}{q(x)}. 
$$
since
$$
p(x)\int_Y p(y | x)\log \frac{p(y|x)}{q(y|x)}dy
$$
is always positive, then
$$
p(x) \log \frac{p(x)}{q(x)} \leq \int_Y p(x, y) \log \frac{p(x,y)}{q(x,y)}dy 
$$
which implies, as already mentioned,
$$
\int_X p(x)\log\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}dx \leq \int_X \int_Yp(x,y)\log\frac{p(x,y)}dx{q(x,y)}dy.
$$